# Movie where 3 aliens who look like hairless human children crash land

Tags: story-identification

They are assisted by a couple teens who find them. They have advanced healing abilities. There is a scene where the teens are having sex (discreetly done) and the 'boys' are watching them out of curiosity.
It's just the five being chased by the military, but it seemed like a neat movie. I saw it in the eighties.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [**Wavelength**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086571/) from 1983?

> Two young lovers learn that a small group of child-like space aliens
>   are marooned on Earth and are being held prisoner at a top secret
>   military facility. The couple then decide to liberate the
>   extraterrestrial castaways and help them make a rendezvous with a
>   rescue ship sent from the alien home planet.

Comment: For the record, this film is **dreadful**. Might I suggest that instead of watching it, you use the 1.5 hours to practice saying the alphabet backwards or learn to cook the perfect omelette.

Comment: I liked the soundtrack, by Tangerine Dream.